# How can i create one play/pause button like youtube in black berry java?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i want to create a  play/pause button like youtube in blackberry java,how can we handle two actions with single button i.e when the button is clicked  for first time it should paly the audio,and again,if the  same button is clicked  again the audio should be stopped,how can we handle two actions with single button and how can we change the images like play/ pause?

Comment: set flag(Boolean) for the button. then check with the corresponding flag value.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

import net.rim.device.api.system.*;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;

public class CustomImageButtonApp extends UiApplication
{
static Bitmap image;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CustomImageButtonApp app = new CustomImageButtonApp ();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}
public CustomImageButtonApp ()
{
 final imagebutton img_btn = new imagebutton("",Field.FOCUSABLE, "play.png",
 "pause.png", 0x9cbe95);
    MainScreen screen=new MainScreen();
     pushScreen(screen);
     screen.setTitle("title");
     screen.add(img_btn);
 }




public class CustomImageButton extends Field  {

    private String _label;
    private int _labelHeight;
    private int _labelWidth;
    private Font _font;   
    private Bitmap _currentPicture;
    private Bitmap _playPicture;
    private Bitmap _pausePicture;
    int color;


    public  CustomImageButton (String text, long style ,String playimg, String pauseimg, int color){
           super(style);

        _playPicture= Bitmap.getBitmapResource( playimg );
        _pausePicture=Bitmap.getBitmapResource( pauseimg );

        _font = getFont();
        _label = text;
        _labelHeight = _playPicture.getHeight(); 
        _labelWidth = _pausePicture.getWidth();

        this.color = color;

        _currentPicture = _playPicture;
    }


    /**
     * @return The text on the button
     */
    String getText(){
        return _label;
    }


   /**
     * Field implementation.
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#getPreferredHeight()
     */
    public int getPreferredHeight(){
        return _labelHeight;
    }

     /**
     * Field implementation.
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#getPreferredWidth()
     */
    public int getPreferredWidth(){
        return _labelWidth;
    }


    /**
     * Field implementation. 
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#drawFocus(Graphics, boolean)
     */
    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
     // Do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Field implementation.
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#layout(int, int)
     */
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(Math.min( width, getPreferredWidth()),
        Math.min( height, getPreferredHeight()));
    }
    /**
     * Field implementation.
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#paint(Graphics)
     */
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics){     
        // First draw the background colour and picture
        graphics.setColor(this.color);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), _currentPicture, 0, 0);

        // Then draw the text
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.setFont(_font);
        graphics.drawText(_label, 4, 2,
            (int)( getStyle() & DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | DrawStyle.HALIGN_MASK ),
            getWidth() - 6 );
    }

    /**
     * Overridden so that the Event Dispatch thread can catch this event
     * instead of having it be caught here..
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#navigationClick(int, int)
     */
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

      if (_currentPicture ==  _playPicture) {
             _currentPicture =  _pausePicture;
            // invalidate(); 

         } else {
             _currentPicture = _playPicture;
             //invalidate(); 

         }

         //fieldChangeNotify(1);
         return true;

}
}
}
```